# What is the result of arcLength for a contour?

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I searched for `arcLength` in Google, and okay maybe I can understand it, but how does it work for contours in an image in EmguCV or OpenCV? I tried to make a little image using MATLAB. The image was `9 x 9` and I draw a line in my image and that line was 1 pixel. I am using this code in EmguCV to detect contours:

```
VectorOfVectorOfPoint cons = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

        CvInvoke.FindContours(img_gray, cons, null, RetrType.List, ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxNone);
        for(int i=0; i<cons.Size;i++)
        {
            VectorOfPoint points = cons[i];
            for(int x =0; x<points.Size;x++)
            {
               temp[points[x]] = new Gray(255);
            }
           double c= CvInvoke.ArcLength(cons[i], true);
            textBox1.Text = c.ToString();             
        }

        imageBox2.Image = temp;
```

`arcLength` was:

- When line is 1 pixel -> `arcLength` was 0.
- When line is 2 pixel -> `arcLength` was 2.
- When line is 3 pixel -> `arcLength` was 4.

This is my image when line is 3 pixel.

[image]

Can any one explain the results to me?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`arcLength`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga8d26483c636be6b35c3ec6335798a47c) does exactly what it claims:

> Calculates a contour perimeter or a curve length.

In your example(s), you're getting fooled by a specific issue with [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0)(!), namely when applied to 1 pixel wide lines! (Implementation issue, algorithm issue, general issue with "border following", ...!?)

Let's have a look at the following examples (sorry for using the Python API here, but the concept should become clear).

---

**Example 1:** `3 x 1` white line on black image

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate 5 x 5 black image
img = np.zeros((5, 5), np.uint8)

# Draw 3 x 1 white line
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (1, 1), (3, 1), 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

# Outputs
print(img, '\n')                                    # Image
print(np.squeeze(cnts[0]), '\n')                    # Contour
print('Contour points:', cnts[0].shape[0], '\n')    
print('arcLength:', cv2.arcLength(cnts[0], True))
```

Output:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255 255 255   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]] 

[[1 1]
 [2 1]
 [3 1]
 [2 1]] 

Contour points: 4 

arcLength: 4.0
```

Please notice, that `[2 1]` occurs twice in the contour, so we have four contour points in total, and each "distance" between two neighbouring contour points is 1, thus the contour perimeter (= arc length) is also 4.

---

**Example 2:** `3 x 2` white rectangle on black image

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate 5 x 5 black image
img = np.zeros((5, 5), np.uint8)

# Draw 3 x 2 white rectangle
img = cv2.rectangle(img, (1, 1), (3, 2), 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

# Outputs
print(img, '\n')                                    # Image
print(np.squeeze(cnts[0]), '\n')                    # Contour
print('Contour points:', cnts[0].shape[0], '\n')
print('arcLength:', cv2.arcLength(cnts[0], True))
```

Output:

```
[[  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0 255 255 255   0]
 [  0 255 255 255   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0   0   0]] 

[[1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 2]
 [3 2]
 [3 1]
 [2 1]] 

Contour points: 6 

arcLength: 6.0
```

We get six contour points, and again each "distance" between two neighbouring contour points is 1, so that the contour perimeter (= arc length) is also 6 –  which seems (more) reasonable.

---

**Example 3:** White circle with radius `2` on black image

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Generate 5 x 5 black image
img = np.zeros((5, 5), np.uint8)

# Draw white circle with radius 2
img = cv2.circle(img, (2, 2), 2, 255, cv2.FILLED)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[0]

# Outputs
print(img, '\n')                                    # Image
print(np.squeeze(cnts[0]), '\n')                    # Contour
print('Contour points:', cnts[0].shape[0], '\n')
print('arcLength:', cv2.arcLength(cnts[0], True))
```

Output:

```
[[  0   0 255   0   0]
 [  0 255 255 255   0]
 [255 255 255 255 255]
 [  0 255 255 255   0]
 [  0   0 255   0   0]] 

[[2 0]
 [1 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 3]
 [2 4]
 [3 3]
 [4 2]
 [3 1]] 

Contour points: 8 

arcLength: 11.313708305358887
```

The "distance" from `[2 0]` to `[1 1]` is 1.414... (square root of 2). Each two neighbouring contour points have that distance (see the image), so we have a contour perimeter (= arc length) of 8 * 1.414... = 11.313...

---

Hope that helps understanding!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```